# Python logic circuit

Tags: python, class, oop, initialization, circuit

I copy this program from a video, I think the `__init__` function in the AndGate class is unnecessary because there is no new instances to be define in the AndGate class. Can someone confirm my reasoning?

```
class LogicGate:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.label = n
        self.output = None

    def getLabel(self):
        return self.label

    def getOutput(self):
        self.output = self.performGateLogic()
        return self.output


class BinaryGate(LogicGate):
    def __init__(self,n):
        LogicGate.__init__(self,n)
        self.pinA = None
        self.pinB = None
    def SetNextPin(self,source):
        if self.pinA == None:
            self.pinA = source #pin a became a instance of connector class, conntector.gate.pinA
        else:
            if self.pinB == None:
                self.pinB = source
            else:
               raise RuntimeError("Error: NO EMPTY PINS")

    def getA(self):
        if self.pinA == None:
            return int(input("Enter Pin A input for gate "+self.getLabel()+"-->"))
        else:
            return self.pinA.getfg().getOutput()

    def getB(self):
        if self.pinB == None:
            return int(input("Enter Pin B input for gate "+self.getLabel()+"-->"))
        else:
            return self.pinB.getfg().getOutput()


class AndGate(BinaryGate):
    def __init__(self,n):
        BinaryGate.__init__(self,n)

    def performGateLogic(self):
        a = self.getA()
        b = self.getB()

        if a == 1:
            if a == b:
                return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

Comment: How about you try, and see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the `__init__` under the `AndGate` class is not necessary. (Tested in python with this specific example and a new class to verify). It has to do with how inheritance in python is handled: the `__init__` function of the parent class is automatically called.